# Why can't we use if or for loop ,while globally in C

Tags: c, conditional-statements, statements

```
#include <stdio.h>

if(1)
{
}

int main() 
{
    printf("Hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can only put executable code inside a function body.  At the top-level, there is no execution, only declarations and static initializations.

Comment: When do you imagine would a while loop be entered?

Comment: "Why is the language the way it is" questions generally cannot be answered, considering C is fifty years old and the people who made the key design decisions aren't here.

Answer (score 2):

`if(1) {}` is a (selection) statement (6.8.4) and statements are only allowed in function definitions (6.9.1).  See [Programming Language - C (draft)](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) for the relevant sections, also refer to the informative Annex A.

Answer (score 0):

We could have had a similar mechanism to `sh`-scripts where it just goes though the file line-by-line, without `main`. However, having an agreed-upon entry-point allows compilers to abstract compiling from linking for multi-compilation-unit programmes and libraries.

[Dennis Ritchie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie) and [Ken Thompson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Thompson) developed it after [B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language)). This was based on [BCPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCPL), developed by [Martin Richards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Richards_(computer_scientist)). This had a `LET START()`, much in the way of [Fortran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran), from The FORTRAN Automatic Coding System:

> a basic block is a stretch of program which has one entry point and
> one exit point

In that way, going from an [`sh`-script to `C`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shc_(shell_script_compiler)) is entirely possible, but not the other way around.